# ES6 Destructuring imports and apply an "as"

Tags: ecmascript-6

I would like to know if something like:

```js
import {  faPause,
  faLevelUpAlt,
  faExchangeAlt,
  faCircle,
} as SolidIcons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

=> SolidIcons.faPause
```

I know there is:

```js
import * as everything from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
=> everything.faPause
```

But that is not what I want because it imports everything from the library..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you've listed is possible under [the syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax), but you should be able to bundle your imports into an object after the fact to simulate it. Something like

```js
import {  faPause,
  faLevelUpAlt,
  faExchangeAlt,
  faCircle,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const SolidIcons = {  faPause,
  faLevelUpAlt,
  faExchangeAlt,
  faCircle,
};
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i've done but there is duplication code :'( And if you have like 100 imports it's begin to be ugly

Comment: If you're worried about duplication, why are you trying to make yourself repeat typing `SolidIcons.` before each use of these icons?

Comment: because i have to use FontAwesome Library:
`library.add(SolidIcons);`